# Is there a difference between constants defined inside a Go function vs ones defined at the top of a package?

Tags: go, constants

Is there a difference, mainly in performance, between constants defined inside vs outside a function scope?

```
func (this *Person) SetDefaults() *Person{
    const (
        defaultFirstName = "first"
        defaultLastName  = "last"
    )

    //do stuff with constants
    return this
}
```

vs.

```
const (
    defaultFirstName = "first"
    defaultLastName  = "last"
)
func (this *Person) SetDefaults() *Person{
    //do stuff with constants
    return this
}
```

Comment: Two universal answers: (1) if it really matters, write a benchmark and measure it.  (2) unless it changes the algorithmic complexity or involves I/O in some form, it doesn't really matter.  (Even if one form causes a cache miss and the other doesn't, you will never notice in most typical programs.)

Comment: What happens is dependent on the compiler and not on the language so nobody can tell.

Answer (score 7):

The only difference is scoping

Constants are simply swapped out at every reference during compilation.
So there's no difference at run time as to where it came from.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "swapped out at every reference during compilation"? I'm not yet familiar enough with compilation in Go am looking to understand this question/answer better. I had assumed, naively I suppose, that constants would be in the stack frame for their scope, conferring some performance benefit.

Comment: When your program is compiled, the value of the constant is compiled directly into your code at the points where it is used. There is no difference between defining a constant with the value 3 and using that as opposed to using the literal value 3.

Comment: So there is no memory allocation involved in defining the constant? And/or no memory calls when the constant is used?

Comment: correct, no unique allocation happens because you used a const.   Obviously, the value of the const is in memory somewhere.   but as @AndySchweig said, it's the same as if you just put the literal wherever you would have used a const